# Windows 8 dont show up on boot loader after installing 16

Tags: boot

As the title describe windows 8 does not show up on boot loader, it only appers ubuntu, in the following log describes the current status of my laptop

http://paste2.org/DKYvOm1p

Hope sb can helps to recover windows boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot into ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` command on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to confirm that Windows is still installed and hasn't been erased by mistake during the installation, the easiest way of doing that is by installing Gparted and checking from Ubuntu (can be found in the store) and note the partition number to add it from the next step.

One confirmed that Windows exists and hasn't been erased by mistake, install Grub customizer and edit the boot file easily by adding Windows 8 back to the booting menu :)

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install grub-customizer**

After installing it enter Grub customizer and enter your password, you should be able to see Windows 8 as an option in the Grub menu and you can edit it to run normally once again.

Answer (score 0):

Just use boot-repair and your problem will be solved, if windows is still installed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

launch Boot-Repair from either :

1. the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)

   or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal
2. Then click the "Recommended repair" button.

I often have this problem and it always solve it, more information at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. Let me know if it worked.